# How to get string value from string array in Android

Tags: android, string, arrays

I am trying to create an application that reads an NFC tag and checks the tag against strings in a string array and then sets the text on another activity. I have got it working so that it checks if the string exists and sets the text in the new activity, but I want to be able to specify which string I want it to check against within the array, because there will be multiple strings in the NFC tag that I want to then display in the new activity. I have tried this for it:

```
result == getResources().getString(R.string.test_dd)
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
String[] dd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dd = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.device_description);

}

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
            if(doesArrayContain(dd, result)) {
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(800);
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabsTest.class);
                    Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
                    bundle1.putString("key", result);
                    newIntent.putExtras(bundle1);
                    startActivity(newIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NFC tag written successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result + " is not in the device description!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the method used and please can anyone help me with this problem:

```
public static boolean doesArrayContain(String[] array, String text) {
    for (String element : array) {
        if(element != null && element.equalsIgnoreCase(text)) {
             return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: work on your java basics.

Comment: Your `doesArrayContain()` seems ok to me

Answer (score 1):

For comparing equality of strings (and other objects) use the `equals()` method. `==` compares identity of objects (same string object).

Comment: I tried that as in doesArrayContain(dd, result) && result.equals(R.is.test_dd) but that didn't work and I didn't think that it would. How would be the best way to implement equals() in to my code efficiently?

Comment: @JamesMeade `R.string.test_dd` is an integer. It is of course not equal to a string. So you must first retrieve the string resource denoted by `R.string.test_dd` and compare that against `result`

Comment: I just worked out that I was doing that wrong and I tried result.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.test_dd)) and adding an int to the method and adding && text.equals(id), but that doesn't work either. Do you have any more tips? You have been very useful thank you!

Comment: @JamesMeade In `doesArrayContain()` you used `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`. Probably you should use it here, too: `result.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(R.string.test_dd))`. Adding `&& text.equals(id)` will always fail if `text` is `String` and `id` is integer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I found:

Create a new method:

```
public static boolean stringCaseInsensitive(String string, String result) {
        if(string != null && string.equalsIgnoreCase(result)) {
             return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

And call it in like this:

```
if(stringCaseInsensitive(getResources().getString(R.string.test_dd), result)) 
                {
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TabsTest.class);
                    Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
                    bundle1.putString("key", result);
                    newIntent.putExtras(bundle1);
                    startActivity(newIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NFC tag written successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                }
```